# Selenium WebDriver (JAVA) - Fluent wait seems not to be working HALP

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, wait, fluentwait

After some time searching for the issue I have I could not encounter any solution. So here I am.

Some background, I am trying to automate the sign up, confirmation and join for a "Live Class" for certain platform.

To do so, you have every 10 minutes a 5 minutes window where you can sign up, then confirm, then wait X time then Join the live class.

But this is just for the first part, where I want to sign up. This is what I did using fluent wait:

```
public void joinPrivateClass() {

    System.out.println("Starting join private class");

             Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(480))
            .pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);


    WebElement signUp = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
            WebElement signUpButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"live-class-322102\"]/div[1]/div/div/button"));

            if(signUpButton.isDisplayed()){
                System.out.println("button is displayed");
            }   else {
                System.out.println("button is not displayed yet");
            }
            return signUpButton;
        }
    }); signUp.click();


}
```

My issue is that after the page is loaded, while the fluentwait "works" I expected to have a "Button is not displayed" every 5 sec until it is and then gets clicked. but while the button is displayed or not I am not getting any message neither the "Button is not displayed" nor "The button is displayed" so I would assume that something is failing in the "wait.until"

Some things to mention, I am not a programmer so sorry if I did something wrong,

Also in my IDE (intelliJ) it marks me the "driver" of this portion of code

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
```

In "purple" and this "driver" :

```
public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver)
```

in GREY if it has anything to do with! thanks for your precious help

Answer (score -1):

Your `wait` is built with `ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)`. So as long as the button does not exist, your `wait.until(...)` will just silently keep failing at the `findElement(...)` line - it will never make it to the `println(...)`.

Remove the `ignoring(...)` from your wait, and change your `wait.until(...)` body to something like:

```
WebElement signUpButton;
try {
    signUpButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"live-class-322102\"]/div[1]/div/div/button"));
    System.out.println("button is displayed");
} catch(NoSuchElementException ignored) {
    System.out.println("button is not displayed yet");
}
return signUpButton;
```